# Após muita pesquisa, cheguei à conclusão que este problema não tem solução, no Python

Tags: python, combobox, pysimplegui

Estou fazendo um cadastro de despesas, em Python, onde uso a interface PySimpleGui.  No campo "fornecedor", busco dados de outra tabela, através de um "combobox". A informação vem correta, mas acrescida de caracteres estranhos, por exemplo:('Magna Comercial Agrícola Ltda',), onde deveria ser somente Magna Comercial Agrícola Ltda.  Não preciso que respondam, apenas eu gostaria de dizer que após muito estudo, cheguei à conclusão que não há solução para o problema dentro do Python. Vou usar outra linguagem.

Eis o código:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import mysql.connector

def busca_fornecedor():
    database = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="controle_chacara_rosita")
    cursor = database.cursor()
    sql_command = "SELECT nome FROM fornecedores ORDER BY nome  "
    cursor.execute(sql_command)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    database.close()
    return data


def busca_produto():
    database = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="controle_chacara_rosita")
    cursor = database.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT nome FROM `insumos` ORDER BY nome "
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    database.close()
    return data

def salvando_dados_para_o_arquivo():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="controle_chacara_rosita")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    sql = "INSERT INTO despesas_02 (data, produto, fornecedor, nota_fiscal, quantidade, unidade, valor_unitario, " \
          "valor_total) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

    data = (values['-DATA-'],
            str(values['-PRODUTO-']),
            str(values['-FORNECEDOR-']),
            values['-NOTA_FISCAL-'],
            values['-QUANTIDADE-'],
            values['-UNIDADE-'],
            values['-VALOR_UNITARIO-'],
            values['-VALOR_TOTAL-'],
            )

    cursor.execute(sql, data)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

    sg.popup(f'Registro {values["-PRODUTO-"]} incluido com sucesso')
    window.Refresh()
    dados_lista = list(tabela.get())
    tabela.update(values=dados_lista)

def update():
    conexao = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="controle_chacara_rosita")
    cursor = conexao.cursor()
    sql = "UPDATE despesas_02 SET data = %s, produto = %s, fornecedor = %s, nota_fiscal = %s, quantidade = %s, " \
          "unidade = %s, valor_unitario = %s, valor_total = %s WHERE codigo = %s"

    data = (values['-DATA-'],
            str(values['-PRODUTO-']),
            str(values['-FORNECEDOR-']),
            values['-NOTA_FISCAL-'],
            values['-QUANTIDADE-'],
            values['-UNIDADE-'],
            values['-VALOR_UNITARIO-'],
            values['-VALOR_TOTAL-'],
            values['-CODIGO-'])

    cursor.execute(sql, data)
    conexao.commit()
    recordsaffected = cursor.rowcount
    cursor.close()
    conexao.close()


    #  dados_lista = list(tabela.get())
    dados_lista[tabela.SelectedRows[0]] = values['-CODIGO-'], values['-DATA-'], values['-PRODUTO-'], values['-FORNECEDOR-'], \
                                          values['-NOTA_FISCAL-'], values['-QUANTIDADE-'], values['-UNIDADE-'], \
                                          values['-VALOR_UNITARIO-'], values['-VALOR_TOTAL-'],

    tabela.update(values=dados_lista)

    print(recordsaffected, " registros alterados")

    sg.popup('Registro ', values['-PRODUTO-'], ' editado, com sucesso',
             background_color='green', text_color='yellow')



def read_task():
    database = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="controle_chacara_rosita")
    cursor = database.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT codigo, data, produto, fornecedor, nota_fiscal, '
                   'quantidade, unidade, valor_unitario, valor_total FROM despesas_02 ORDER BY data')

    data = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    database.close()
    return data


dados_lista = read_task()
data_values = dados_lista

# Definindo a janela layout
data_headings = ['COD.', 'DT COMPRA', 'PRODUTO', 'FORNECEDOR', 'NOTA FISCAL', 'QTDE', 'UNID', 'VALOR UNIT.',
                 'VALOR TOT.']

data_cols_width = [5, 10, 26, 40, 20, 8, 8, 10, 10]
tabela = sg.Table(
    values=dados_lista,
    headings=data_headings,
    col_widths=data_cols_width,
    auto_size_columns=False,
    font='verdana 10',
    text_color='white',
    alternating_row_color='#848887',
    bind_return_key=True,
    enable_events=True,
    justification='left',
    change_submits=True,
    num_rows=32,
    key='-FILESTABLE-')

layout = [

             [sg.Frame('Despesas da chácara', [[(tabela)]])],  # Ok. Funcionando.
             [sg.Frame('Manutenção da Tabela',
                       [[sg.Text('_' * 270, text_color='blue')],

                        [sg.Text('CÓDIGO:', font='Verdana 10', text_color='yellow'),
                         sg.InputText(' ', size=(4, 5), readonly=True, text_color='brown', background_color='blue',
                                      do_not_clear=False, key='-CODIGO-'),
                         sg.Text('DATA DA COMPRA', font='verdana 10'),

                         sg.InputText(size=(14, 3), key='-DATA-'),

                         sg.Text('PRODUTO:', font='Verdana 10'),
                         sg.Combo(busca_produto(), key='-PRODUTO-'),

                        sg.Text('FORNECEDOR:', font='Verdana 10', tooltip='Escolha o fornecedor'),
                         sg.Combo(busca_fornecedor(), key='-FORNECEDOR-'),

                         sg.Text('NOTA FISCAL:', font='Verdana 10'),
                         sg.InputText(' ', size=(44, 5), do_not_clear=False, key='-NOTA_FISCAL-')],

                        [sg.Text('QUANTIDADE:', font='Verdana 10'),
                         sg.InputText(' ', justification='right', size=(10, 5), do_not_clear=False, key='-QUANTIDADE-'),

                         sg.Text('UNIDADE:', font='Verdana 10'),
                         sg.InputText(' ', size=(10, 5), do_not_clear=False, key='-UNIDADE-', justification='right'),

                         sg.Text('VALOR UNITÁRIO:', font='Verdana 10'),
                         sg.InputText(' ', size=(32, 5), do_not_clear=False, key='-VALOR_UNITARIO-',
                                      justification='right'),

                         sg.Text('VALOR TOTAL:', font='Verdana 10'),
                         sg.InputText(' ', size=(32, 5), do_not_clear=False, justification='right',
                                      key='-VALOR_TOTAL-')],

                        [sg.Text('_' * 270, text_color='blue')]])],
             [sg.Button(' ', size=(39, 1)),
              sg.Button('Criar / Editar', size=(19, 1), button_color=('blue', 'orange'),
                        key='-CRIAR_EDITAR-', font='Verdana 10'),
              sg.Button('Deletar', size=(19, 1), button_color=('blue', 'orange'), key='-DELETAR-',
                        font=('Verdana 10')),
              sg.Button('Limpar campos', size=(19, 1), button_color=('blue', 'orange'), key='-LIMPAR_CAMPOS-',
                        font=('Verdana 10')),
              sg.Button('Sair', size=(19, 1), button_color=('blue', 'orange'), key='-SAIR-', font='Verdana 10'),
              sg.Button(' ', size=(39, 1))]

         ],

window = sg.Window('Despesas com a chácara da Rosita', layout[0],
                   default_element_size=(40, 1), grab_anywhere=False, resizable=True, finalize=True)
window.maximize()

# Read  values entered by user
while True:
    event, values = window.read()  # Read  values entered by user

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:  # If  is closed by user terminate While Loop
        break

    if event == '-FILESTABLE-':
        data_selected = [tabela.get()[row] for row in values[event]]
        if data_selected != []:
            window['-CODIGO-'].Update(data_selected[0][0])
            window['-DATA-'].update(data_selected[0][1])
            window['-PRODUTO-'].update(data_selected[0][2])
            window['-FORNECEDOR-'].update(data_selected[0][3])
            window['-NOTA_FISCAL-'].update(data_selected[0][4])
            window['-QUANTIDADE-'].update(data_selected[0][5])
            window['-UNIDADE-'].update(data_selected[0][6])
            window['-VALOR_UNITARIO-'].update(data_selected[0][7])
            window['-VALOR_TOTAL-'].update(data_selected[0][8])

    if event == '-CRIAR_EDITAR-':
        if values['-CODIGO-'] == '':
            salvando_dados_para_o_arquivo()
        else:
            update()

    if event == '-LIMPAR_CAMPOS-':
        limpar_campos()

    if event == '-DELETAR-':
        deletar()

    if event == '-SAIR-':
        break
```

Tela com o retorno dos dados

[image: 1]

Comment: posso estar errado, mas isso parece um erro frequente que vem acontecendo com os novos programadores confundem 'python é facil de usar' como não precisa estudar, não estou falando que é seu caso, mas é muito comum de se ver. mesmo que não queira saber, o resultado é uma tupla, e vc deveria pegar o primeiro valor.

Comment: Elton, obrigado pelo seu comentário.  Eu sei que é uma tupla e se eu pegar somente o primeiro valor,[0], ele vem correto, mas não é isso que eu preciso.  O combobox foi colocado ali para que o usuário possa escolher qualquer valor e não somente o primeiro.  Por isso estou convicto que não existe solução dentro do Python.  Provavelmente as quatro pessoas que deram -1 para meu questionamento, nunca passaram por uma situação assim e nem sabem que o Python tem uma interface gráfica, chamada PySimpleGui.

Comment: ja passei muito por isso, prefiro usar tkinter, e ultimamente estou tentando pygame, não sei exatamente o funcionamento do seu codigo, mas vi, cursor.fetchall(), isso retorna uma lista, mesmo que apenas um valor dentro, não é ai o problema? vc pode estar esperando 1 valor, mas retorna 1 valor dentro de uma lista

Answer (score 0):

A resposta mais aproximada para a minha pergunta, é esta:

## ============  Início  ==================

def find_product():
conn = sqlite3.connect('controller.db')
conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_name ")
data = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
print(data)
return data

## ===============  Fim  ================

Não é a solução, cem por cento, porque não funciona com o banco de dados MariaDB, mas funciona muito bem com Sqlite.
Troquei o banco de dados e estou satisfeito com o resultado.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).